# How to apply Batchnorm and Temporal Convolutions To Temporarly Variant Data?

Tags: pytorch, time-series, conv-neural-network, classification

My task is to implement the architecture discussed [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2211.01367.pdf). I am currently implementing a sub-network, where the input tensor is of shape (N, T/4, 832), where T is time. The sub-network consists of "Temporal Linear Layer -> Batch Norm -> Relu -> Temporal Convolution. My issue lies in implementation, how can I apply a temporal batchnorm & temporal convolution to a variable T?

My current implementation of the sub-network in Pytorch is as follows:

```
nn.Sequential(
nn.Linear(832, 832), # Input: N x T/4 x 832
nn.BatchNorm1d(832), # Input : N x 832 x T/4
nn.ReLU(),
nn.Conv1d(832,832) # Input: N x 832 x T/4
# Output: N x 832 x T/4 - 2
)
```

The issue is that Conv1d is downsampling the T dimension. Which is not, correct hence my question. It's hard to find any resources on what precisely a temporal convolution is.

Answer (score 0):

Without padding, convolution output size will be reduced relative to the input size. See the description of the padding parameter for [pytorch Conv1D](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv1d.html). Specifying "same"for this parameter will ensure that the output and input sizes are the same for the dimension along which convolution is performed.

> padding controls the amount of padding applied to the input. It can be either a string {‘valid’, ‘same’} or a tuple of ints giving the amount of implicit padding applied on both sides.